# What is the right way to save time values in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I'll have to save various working hours (open and closes) and wonder what is the best format/way to use ?
Sure I can choose to have `time` time as DB type for these values and format the DB time like that:

```
Time.current.to_s(:time)
=> "15:52"
```

Instead of `Time.current` I'll be select the corresponding time value from the DB:

```
Thu, 12 Apr 2018 15:48:28 UTC +00:00
```

But what is solution to choose for a User to enter time values in the front-end ? Moreover, I'll have to either choose a general format for hours, like

```
07:30
```

Or (it the requirement changes) enable a locale-dependent format like this:

```
7ч30 (for Russia)
7h30 (for France)
etc..
```

Any ideas and tips ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'd store "seconds from midnight", so 15:52 would be stored as the integer 57120.  Then I'd write a custom type [see the `attribute` docs for more details](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Attributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-attribute) that converts to/from that integer.

Then I'd just have different formats in the locale file that I'd use for that conversion.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. I'll take a look at that. I still hesitate between writing my own attribute or use tod (https://github.com/JackC/tod) or time_of_day_attr (https://github.com/tlemens/time_of_day_attr) gem.

Comment: `tod` doesn't seem locale aware, but if they work then all good.